# Limbo not playing on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

It's been long I played Limbo and when I saw Inside decided to play it again. I played it on my Windows two years ago, ever since I've been using Ubuntu because of work. I downloaded the .exe and tried running it with wine, installation completes but every time i try to run it, a notification box pops-up with error message:

```
Vertex shader error: memory:17:8: error: syntax error, unexpected KW_TEXTURE
```

please how do I get it to work? thanks.
I also have playOnLinux

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps: I am assuming you have installed limbo using playonlinux

1. Click on the game icon inside playonlinux and then click configure.
2. Go to installed component tab.
3. Install the following packages:
    **vcrun2013, dxfullsetup and dotnet45**.

Simply put, all those dependencies that this game requires to be playable on windows, must be installed on Linux as well. 
 P.S. Three package mentioned above worked for me, you might need to install more based on your system.